# Cannot visit newly created site using multisite Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, multisite

I have enabled Wordpress Multisite and created a new website using it.

Main site: [lafznama.com](https://lafznama.com)

New site: [lafznama.com/books](https://lafznama.com/books)

When I go to new site, it shows error: "Error establishing a database connection".

Q: How to resolve it?

Q: Should I create "books" folder in directory and add a clone copy of Wordpress and also clone MySQL database too?

Here is the wp-config settings which enabled multisite Wordpress:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'lafznama.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Also, here are the settings for .htaccess provided by multisite Wordpress, I applied:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The issue is also highlighted here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

before “That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging.”

or test in new php file

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password'); 

echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysqli_close($link); 
?>
```

or recheck in wp-config

```
define('DB_NAME', 'db name'); 
define('DB_USER', 'db user'); 
define('DB_HOST', 'db localhost etc');
```

Comment: Tried these settings, nothing changed. On the main site (lafznama.com), there is no error and database is connecting without any issue.